# Unipotent representations of SL(2,R) by quantization

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory

I'm a PhD student in mathematical physics and I happen to need some elements of Kirillov's "orbit method" for producing representations of Lie groups. I'm familiar with symplectic geometry, geometric quantization and coadjoint orbits. As regards the present question, I use the terminology of [Witten, "Coadjoint orbits of the Virasoro group"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104160487).

Specifically, my questions are the following:

1. Are all unipotent representations of SL(2,R) known and classified?
2. If yes, is it known how to reproduce these representations by geometric quantization of the "cone-like" coadjoint orbits of SL(2,R)?
3. Same questions for any non-compact, semi-simple Lie group.

I've tried to look for an answer by Googling "unipotent representations SL(2,R)" and similar keywords, but the only search results I got were research papers that were too advanced/obscure to me :-( In any case, sorry in advance if this question is trivial or if it is a duplicate of another math.SE question.